# Fetch data from firestore based on TimeStamp in java/Kotlin/Android || Get TimeStamp in java to compare with firebase TimeStamp

Tags: java, android, firebase, kotlin, google-cloud-firestore

case is to fetch the particular date data from the firebase firestore
and date is stored in my firebase Firestore in the TimeStamp format.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. What exactly would you like to achieve? Can you show us some code that doesn't work the way you expect?

Answer (score 0):

```
val cal = Calendar.getInstance()
    cal[Calendar.YEAR] = 2023
    cal[Calendar.MONTH] = Calendar.JANUARY
    cal[Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH] = 16
    cal[Calendar.HOUR] = 0
    cal[Calendar.MINUTE] = 0
    cal[Calendar.SECOND] = 0
    cal[Calendar.AM_PM] = Calendar.AM
```

output

```
Timestamp(seconds=1673807400, nanoseconds=863000000)
```